# adding a Carriage Return in XSLT using wordml

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, wordml

I am using XSLT (1.0) to generate a Word Document using WordML. I have different tables and in one of the columns i need to add values separated by a carriage return.

I.e : instead of `Lot1Lot2Lot3`, I need:

```
Lot1
Lot2
Lot3
```

I have searched all the related topics but I could not find any solution which could fix my issue. I have tried to use `<w:br/>` or `<xsl:text></xsl:text>` or the dec code &#10/&#13 inside the `<xsl:text>` but didn't  work as I still see the result in the same line.

XML:

```
<Root>
 <elemName>Test</elemName>
 <elemDescription>Description</elemDescription>
 <Items>
  <Item1Flag>Y</Item1Flag>
  <Item1Value>123213123</Item1Flag>
 </Items> 
 <Items>
  <Item1Flag>Y</Item1Flag>
  <Item1Value>12223123</Item1Flag>
 </Items>
 <Items>
  <Item1Flag>Y</Item1Flag>
  <Item1Value>1232423</Item1Flag>
 </Items>
</Root>
```

Stylesheet:

```
...
<w:t><xsl:call-template name="concatItems">
<xsl:with-param name="elements" select="Items[Item1Flag='Y']/Item1Value"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</w:t>
...

<!-- Template -->
<xsl:template name="concatItems">
  <xsl:param name="elements"/>
  <xsl:variable name="result">
    <xsl:for-each select="$elements">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><w:br/></xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>  
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The XPath `Items[Item1Flag='Y']/Item3` looks for an `Item3` child of an `Items` tag that contains an `Item1Flag` with text value `Y`.  I don't see any `Item3` elements inside any of your `Items` elements.  Please [edit] your post and provide consistent input and output.

Comment: Thanks. After hours of testing and research I think I have manage to solve it. I have removed the template usage and just use the code <w:t><xsl:for-each select="Items[Item1Flag='Y']/Item1Value"><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><w:br/></xsl:if></xsl:for-each></w:t>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a template, I have called the for-each directly in the style sheet and use `<w:br/>`.

```
<w:t>
    <xsl:for-each select="Items[Item1Flag='Y']/Item1Value">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <w:br/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</w:t>
```